# Getting "invalid port number" when calling a local script file using PuTTY dynamically

Tags: vbscript, sh, putty

I have to execute a bunch of commands using PuTTY. To automate this process, I am creating a file and placing all commands there dynamically using VBScript. This file is getting created in my local folder. And I am trying to execute this file using PuTTY. But something is not working. I am not able to call this local file..

```
Dim username
Dim password

username = InputBox("Please Enter Your UserID")
password =  InputBox("Please Enter Your Password")

Set fs = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set a =  fs.CreateTextFile("C:\TestFile.sh", True)
a.writeLine("cd /home/bin/")


Set shell = wscript.CreateObject("wscript.Shell")
pcmd = "putty.exe -ssh"&" "&username & "@10.51.12.34 -pw" &" "&password&" "&"-m"&" "&"""c:\Testfile.sh"""
```

I am able to login and the script file is also getting created successfully. But I am getting invalid port number when try to call the `Testfile.sh`.

Please suggest.

Comment: If this is your real code, I'm a bit puzzled how you log in... You save the password to the variable 'password' but give putty a variable 'passwrd' which would be empty (you also declare a third variable 'Pwd' which is not used at all....)

Comment: Sorry for the confusion!!  It was typo.. Those are working fine...

Answer (score 1):

You use the `passwrd`, while you assign a value to the `password`.

So your resulting command-line is:

```
putty.exe -ssh username@10.51.12.34 -pw -m "c:\Testfile.sh"
```

While I'm not getting "invalid port number" error with your command-line syntax, I'm getting similarly confusing error.

All obviously because the PuTTY command-line parser gets confused by the `-pw` switch without a value.

---

You should also close the file before starting PuTTY.

---

Your expression for assembling the command-line is pointlessly complicated.

What about this?

```
pcmd = "putty.exe -ssh " & username & "@10.51.12.34 -pw " & password & " -m ""c:\Testfile.sh"""
```

---

Consider using the `plink.exe`, instead of the `putty.exe`, for automation.
It has the same command-line syntax, but it is a console application.
https://the.earth.li/~sgtatham/putty/latest/htmldoc/Chapter7.html